# How to write a function in the divide-and-conquer style

Tags: plotting, scoping

I'd like to vary a factor in a matrix calculation, so I have used `Module` to make it happened, but it doesn't work. Below is a code example. can someone tell me how to fix it? It would be appreciated.

```
polardata[omega_] := 
  Module[{},
    matrix = Flatten[RandomReal[0.5, {1, 6}], 1];
    intermediate = omega*matrix;
    addition = Flatten[RandomReal[0.5, {1, 6}], 1];
    polardata = Join[intermediate, addition]]

Manipulate[
 ListPolarPlot[polardata[omega], DataRange -> {0, 2 π}, 
   Joined -> True], 
 {omega, 0.1, 1.0}]
```

Comment: Don't define `polardata` inside the definition for `polardata`, you are wiping the `Module` definition as soon as you evaluate it.  Just take the `polardata = ` out of the last line of the `Module` and you are fine.

Comment: You need to read up on how code functions in the Wolfram Language. [Functions and Programs overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html) should help. You appear to be using syntax from another programming language.

Comment: @ Jason B, You're right. It works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ Edmund, I already read those and couples of books, but I guess I am a very slow learner. Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use a programming style that breaks down a procedure into several named steps (and I often use this style myself), then use `Module` properly and localize the names. Further, return the result, do not assign it to the procedure name.

With a few changes along the lines mentioned above, your code will work.

```
 polardata[omega_] :=
   Module[{matrix, intermediate, addition}, 
     matrix = Flatten[RandomReal[0.5, {1, 6}], 1];
     intermediate = omega*matrix;
     addition = Flatten[RandomReal[0.5, {1, 6}], 1];
     Join[intermediate, addition]]

Manipulate[
  ListPolarPlot[polardata[omega], DataRange -> {0, 2 π}, Joined -> True],
  {omega, 0.1, 1.0}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi m_goldberg, yes, it works. Thank you for your help. In addition, I also see that a code also works without anything in Module[{},...]. Just removing " polardata" in Module from my original code seems works fine. I don't have a good intuition to understand this though. Thank you.